# Get specific records

Tags: c#, sql, datetime

I would like to retrieve records between September 1st 2013 to September 1st 2014 
My current method gets the records from September 2014 to September 2015-
But it should be September 2013 to September 2014. 
What I am doing wrong is it because i am getting DateTime.Now?

```
int thisYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
DateTime thisYearStart = new DateTime(thisYear, 9, 1);
DateTime thisYearEnd = thisYearStart.AddYears(1).AddTicks(-1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", thisYearStart);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", thisYearEnd);
```

from this how do i select a distinct records?

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, Name,SName, DOB) AS ROW, * 
    FROM TableName 
    WHERE Date > @Date1 And Date < @Date2
) 
SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE ROW BETWEEN 1 AND 200
```

Comment: That certainly is not SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the follwoing as your startDate and endDate.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year-1,9,1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year,9,1);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", startDate);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time2", endDate);
```

Try this one for distinct

```
WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID, Name,SName, DOB) AS ROW, * 
    FROM TableName 
    WHERE Date > @Date1 And Date < @Date2
) 

SELECT * FROM cte 
WHERE ROW BETWEEN 1 AND 200
```

Comment: but i dont want to manually import the date it should pick up automatically. so every year it gets record from 9 Sep 2013 to 9 Sep 2014

Comment: Final question for some reason my sql query is not working - i am getting repeated list of records how can i apply distinct word to my query (i've updated my question)

Comment: give me few minutes to check it

Comment: I have a question. Where do you want to apply the distinct? On which column?

Comment: I am receiving an error "The column 'ID' was specified multiple times for 'cte'." i try removing ID from `order by` but same error

Comment: doesn't work:( instead select * from if i do select disinct ID, name etc... from cta it works but i only get some records not top 200

Comment: hmm it seems weird, let me check it again and I find anything I will let you know.

Comment: I fixed the problem instead `SELECT *` i did  `SELECT DISTINCT ID, etc..`